# Microphone and speakers not working with NVIDIA GEFORCE under 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa

I run an HP x 360 under Ubuntu 20.0.4 LTS. It has an NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX card in it plus all the standard device interfaces.

When I try to use the built-in microphone it doesn't appear to detect it at all. I can edit the alsa configuration, but am only able to have ***one of*** the sound or the mike working at any given time. In addition it, or at least "Settings", fails to detect the NVIDIA card as a possible output source.

Changing the last three lines of /etc/modeprobe.d/alsa-base.conf (see below) will turn the mike off if I set value = 0, but leave the sound on the speakers. If I try to set the options in these lines so that both are forced on (option >0) both appear in settings but only the mike works (obviously both lines uncommented!)

Note also in the final line that despite the fact that:

`cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec`

gives

```
Codec: Realtek ALC285
Codec: Intel Kabylake HDMI
```

At: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/hd-audio/models.html

Alc285 is only identified as generic Alc28x and a specific codec is not listed. The final line in the config file attempts to use the fix to sort any HP x360 specific issues, but makes little or no difference.

How do I get access to speakers and mike (built-in or USB) to work? Is it a kernel issue

**For reference**:

inxi gives

```
System:    Host: abcde Kernel: 5.4.0-81-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.9 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Convertible System: HP product: HP Spectre x360 Convertible v: N/A serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: HP model: 8519 v: 11.66 serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: AMI v: F.32 date: 09/25/2019 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS driver: sof-audio-pci 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GP107GL High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-81-generic
```

and

`lspci | grep Audio`

gives:

`01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller (rev ff)`

`aplay -l`

gives

````
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 0: HDA Analog (*) []
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 1: HDA Digital (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 3: HDMI1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 4: HDMI2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 5: HDMI3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0aplay -l```

gives
````

/etc/ modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf file looks like:

````
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from being loaded as first soundcard
# options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=1
#options snd-hda-intel model=alc295-hp-x360```
````

Comment: The audio part of graphics cards is output only.

Comment: Please expand. :-)

Comment: There's nothing to expand, comments aren't answers and mine was just a correction to this *detect the NVIDIA card as a possible input/output source*. The Nvidia card will never be detected as input because it has none.

Comment: Point taken. Edited :-)